# Cocos2d-x app only crashes in Ad-hoc build

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, crash-reports, adhoc

My cocos2d-x application crashes in Ad-hoc which built in release after I upgrade to xcode 4.6.

Here is what I did for testing:

1. Use the same app's ipa which built in 4.5.2, no problem
2. Run the app in release through xcode in device, no problem
3. Build the app in debug for ad-hoc, no problem.

The crash report is:

```
Incident Identifier: 8271D2BD-FB0B-4A1F-87BC-C02AF3F61A27
CrashReporter Key:   561c3d85fda95f88dc109d6c0f098b5e4ec968fc
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         SceneBook [4164]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/39E159BE-78B5-45A7-B21B-C1FEEF1A8DFD/SceneBook.app/SceneBook
Identifier:      SceneBook
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-26 16:13:41.224 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x0d270e49
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SceneBook                       0x00085e10 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readFloat() (CCBReader.cpp:520)
1   SceneBook                       0x0008ac38 cocos2d::extension::CCNodeLoader::parsePropTypePosition(cocos2d::CCNode*, cocos2d::CCNode*, cocos2d::extension::CCBReader*, char const*) (CCNodeLoader.cpp:347)
2   SceneBook                       0x0008a0d4 cocos2d::extension::CCNodeLoader::parseProperties(cocos2d::CCNode*, cocos2d::CCNode*, cocos2d::extension::CCBReader*) (CCNodeLoader.cpp:108)
3   SceneBook                       0x000853a4 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readNodeGraph(cocos2d::CCNode*) (CCBReader.cpp:610)
4   SceneBook                       0x00085718 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readNodeGraph(cocos2d::CCNode*) (CCBReader.cpp:719)
5   SceneBook                       0x00084b40 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readFileWithCleanUp(bool, cocos2d::CCDictionary*) (CCBReader.cpp:198)
6   SceneBook                       0x000849c8 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readNodeGraphFromData(cocos2d::extension::CCData*, cocos2d::CCObject*, cocos2d::CCSize const&) (CCBReader.cpp:279)
7   SceneBook                       0x00084506 cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readNodeGraphFromFile(char const*, cocos2d::CCObject*, cocos2d::CCSize const&) (CCBReader.cpp:256)
8   SceneBook                       0x000843de cocos2d::extension::CCBReader::readNodeGraphFromFile(char const*) (CCBReader.cpp:231)
9   SceneBook                       0x00080ff0 CCBLoader::load(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&) (CCBLoader.cpp:29)
10  SceneBook                       0x000803da MainScene::scene() (MainScene.cpp:25)
11  SceneBook                       0x00080c4c IntroScene::makeTransition(cocos2d::CCTime) (IntroScene.cpp:61)
12  SceneBook                       0x000a1adc cocos2d::CCTimer::update(float) + 204
13  SceneBook                       0x000a35ee cocos2d::CCScheduler::update(float) + 326
14  SceneBook                       0x000a0da0 cocos2d::CCDirector::drawScene() + 24
15  SceneBook                       0x000a17a2 cocos2d::CCDisplayLinkDirector::mainLoop() + 34
16  QuartzCore                      0x33302868 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 160
17  QuartzCore                      0x333027be CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 54
18  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x35b4affa IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 150
19  IOKit                           0x350fb606 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 182
20  CoreFoundation                  0x37e88f0c __CFMachPortPerform + 356
21  CoreFoundation                  0x37e9351c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
22  CoreFoundation                  0x37e934be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
23  CoreFoundation                  0x37e9230c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
24  CoreFoundation                  0x37e1549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
25  CoreFoundation                  0x37e15366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
26  GraphicsServices                0x362f8432 GSEventRunModal + 130
27  UIKit                           0x30cc6cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
28  SceneBook                       0x0007f688 main (main.m:14)
29  SceneBook                       0x0007f250 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30b103a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x347eaf04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x347eac22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30b20cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306cf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306ccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30b20cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306cf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306ccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30b10004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30b101fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37e933ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37e92124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37e1549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37e15366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3129dc9c RunWebThread(void*) + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3307272e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x330725e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0c6962b0    r1: 0x0d270e49      r2: 0x0000024d      r3: 0x00000248
    r4: 0x2fe7b4e0    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x0c6962b0      r7: 0x2fe7b448
    r8: 0x0c697310    r9: 0x00000249     r10: 0x0c696d70     r11: 0x42480000
    ip: 0x00000247    sp: 0x2fe7b448      lr: 0x0008ac3f      pc: 0x00085e10
  cpsr: 0x00000030

Binary Images:
   0x7e000 -    0xd4fff +SceneBook armv7  <33aa47646eca3618aac7d05e4d1395df> /var/mobile/Applications/39E159BE-78B5-45A7-B21B-C1FEEF1A8DFD/SceneBook.app/SceneBook
0x2fe7d000 - 0x2fe9efff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3039e000 - 0x3039efff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30470000 - 0x30548fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30579000 - 0x30583fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x30659000 - 0x3091afff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3092c000 - 0x30934fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x30937000 - 0x3095cfff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x309a9000 - 0x309a9fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30b0f000 - 0x30b25fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x30b6b000 - 0x30b7cfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30b7d000 - 0x30c2afff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30c2b000 - 0x30c41fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30c95000 - 0x31137fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x311b5000 - 0x311f0fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x311f4000 - 0x319b3fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31a18000 - 0x31b61fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x31c14000 - 0x31ce3fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x31d1d000 - 0x31d6efff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31db2000 - 0x31eb8fff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <7454a840600038949d67edad05097242> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x31eb9000 - 0x31ebefff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x32106000 - 0x32109fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3210a000 - 0x3214ffff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x32157000 - 0x32163fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32166000 - 0x3219bfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32226000 - 0x32226fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x32227000 - 0x32246fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3249f000 - 0x324a4fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x324a5000 - 0x324a6fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x324a7000 - 0x324aafff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3262b000 - 0x32663fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32b28000 - 0x32b6bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x32d19000 - 0x32d2afff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32dc6000 - 0x32dcafff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32f29000 - 0x32f35fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x32f43000 - 0x32f46fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x32fea000 - 0x33063fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33064000 - 0x330f0fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x330f1000 - 0x330f2fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33158000 - 0x3315cfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x331e7000 - 0x332adfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x332ae000 - 0x3339ffff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x333a0000 - 0x333a6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x335c5000 - 0x335c9fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33672000 - 0x3367bfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3369b000 - 0x336e5fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3375d000 - 0x33763fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33768000 - 0x33925fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33a27000 - 0x33a40fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33ef1000 - 0x33f49fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34017000 - 0x34026fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3404a000 - 0x3404cfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x341fd000 - 0x342c3fff  GLEngine armv7  <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x344b4000 - 0x34698fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x346a2000 - 0x34790fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34794000 - 0x347a8fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x347e7000 - 0x347fdfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x34914000 - 0x34915fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x34c4c000 - 0x34c6cfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x34d83000 - 0x34e02fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34e31000 - 0x34e35fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34ee5000 - 0x34f02fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35066000 - 0x35069fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x350d8000 - 0x350d8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x350f7000 - 0x35135fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35136000 - 0x35136fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x359b9000 - 0x359bffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x359c0000 - 0x359f7fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35a68000 - 0x35a8bfff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35a8c000 - 0x35ab0fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35ab1000 - 0x35af9fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x35afa000 - 0x35b46fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35b47000 - 0x35b4bfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35b4f000 - 0x35b53fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35b8a000 - 0x35b8cfff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x35b8d000 - 0x35b90fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35d6e000 - 0x35db7fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35dbb000 - 0x35dc6fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35eb0000 - 0x35ef0fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x360a3000 - 0x3617afff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x362e2000 - 0x362ecfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x362ed000 - 0x362f3fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x362f4000 - 0x362fefff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x362ff000 - 0x36307fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36308000 - 0x36317fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36318000 - 0x3643dfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36472000 - 0x369b6fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x369b7000 - 0x369b9fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x369bc000 - 0x369bcfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x369bd000 - 0x369d3fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36d96000 - 0x36d97fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36d98000 - 0x36e08fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x36e75000 - 0x36e76fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36e77000 - 0x36e78fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36f4e000 - 0x36f54fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x36f65000 - 0x36faefff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x36fdd000 - 0x3702efff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x37040000 - 0x371befff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x371bf000 - 0x371d4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3741e000 - 0x374c8fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x374d5000 - 0x374d6fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3751d000 - 0x37533fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x37534000 - 0x3753bfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3761a000 - 0x37664fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x37665000 - 0x37668fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x3768d000 - 0x3768dfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3768e000 - 0x3769bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3769e000 - 0x3776efff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x37772000 - 0x377aefff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x377af000 - 0x377b6fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x377d4000 - 0x377d9fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x37c31000 - 0x37d76fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x37d77000 - 0x37d83fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37e06000 - 0x37f1dfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x37f3d000 - 0x37f8bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37fb1000 - 0x37fc0fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x37fc1000 - 0x38005fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
```

How to debug this problem? Can anybody advise? Thanks

Comment: Not sure at first glance, Try to run the application in developer build (debug mode) and run it on device and see where your application is crashing.

Comment: This crash report is missing the actual crash reason. Exception code, Exception Reason etc. Please post the complete crash report!

Comment: I posted the whole report.

Comment: As I said, I tested my app in release mode and also in debug mode in my device without any problem. It only crashes when I build my app in release mode and as an ad-hoc build.

Comment: Actually my same source code has no problem in Xcode 4.5.2. I don't know whether it's related to Xcode 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out via the Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN.
The CCBReader::readFloat() method may crash due to memory misalignment reason, and only when you build and run the release version of your app.

There is the resolution about this crash:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/18183?r=22190

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is the good answer. 

But one thing is really strange. I can run my app in release mode in my device without problem. It only crashes when I run it when I build my app in Ad-hoc. Anyway after I follow the post, I solved my problem.